# Removing anchor (#hash) from URL

Tags: php

Is there any reliable way in PHP to clean a URL of anchor tags?

So input:

http://site.com/some/#anchor

Outputs:

http://site.com/some/

Answer (score 28, accepted):

#### Using strstr()

```
$url = strstr($url, '#', true);
```

#### Using strtok()

Shorter way, using [`strtok`](http://us.php.net/strtok):

```
$url = strtok($url, "#");
```

#### Using explode()

Alternative way to separate the url from the hash:

```
list ($url, $hash) = explode('#', $url, 2);
```

If you don't want the `$hash` at all, you can omit it in `list`:

```
list ($url) = explode('#', $url);
```

With PHP version >= 5.4 you don't even need to use `list`:

```
$url = explode('#', $url)[0];
```

#### Using preg_replace()

Obligatory regex solution:

```
$url = preg_replace('/#.*/', '', $url);
```

#### Using Purl

[**Purl**](https://github.com/jwage/purl) is neat URL manipulation library:

```
$url = \Purl\Url::parse($url)->set('fragment', '')->getUrl();
```

Comment: Do you think is possible to also check the integrity of the url? I mean, this information (the url) is arriving from a JS code over ajax, so is easy hackable, if some body lets say send me an url like sit#e.com/some this will generate an invalid url after the parsing, how would you check the validity?

Comment: Use `filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)` + test if it starts with `http://` or `https://`.

Comment: It's important to be aware that `strstr` returns `false` if no `#` was found. All other solutions return the original url.

Comment: first example will return an empty result if url has no anchor. not so smart

Comment: strstr will return false if there is no "#" in the URL.
strtok will return "test" if the original URL was "#test", while we might expect an empty string. explode is the only reliable one...

Answer (score 3):

There is also one other option with [parse_url()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php);

```
$str = 'http://site.com/some/#anchor';
$arr = parse_url($str);
echo $arr['scheme'].'://'.$arr['host'].$arr['path'];
```

Output:

```
http://site.com/some/
```

Comment: This is also trashing the port, query, and other url parts

Comment: It's true but in his case it works good output is as he wanted. In decription of `parse_url` he can read more about it but I don't think he will choose this option so this answer is only to show the alternatives.

Comment: @Robert: Actually I think this answer is way better, since the knowledge of the structure of the URL is encapsulated. Chances are pretty large than using regexes or string manipulation, one will forget some scenario's whereas dedicated methods are more reliable.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative way

```
$url = 'http://site.com/some/#anchor';
echo str_replace('#'.parse_url($url,PHP_URL_FRAGMENT),'',$url);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using parse_url():

```
function removeURLFragment($pstr_urlAddress = '') {
    $larr_urlAddress = parse_url ( $pstr_urlAddress );
    return $larr_urlAddress['scheme'].'://'.(isset($larr_urlAddress['user']) ? $larr_urlAddress['user'].':'.''.$larr_urlAddress['pass'].'@' : '').$larr_urlAddress['host'].(isset($larr_urlAddress['port']) ? ':'.$larr_urlAddress['port'] : '').$larr_urlAddress['path'].(isset($larr_urlAddress['query']) ? '?'.$larr_urlAddress['query'] : '');
}
```