# How to redirect page to a URL without hash (#) in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, .htaccess, redirect

**Preface:**

I am at following address:

```
http://www.example.com/#contact
```

After successful contact form submission, the user is redirected to following address:

```
http://www.example.com/thanks
```

With the help of following code:

```
// Redirect to thank you page
redirect_to("thanks");
```

The function redirect_to() is defined as:

```
// Page redirection
function redirect_to($url)
{
    if(isset($url) && $url != '')
    {
        header("Location: " . $url);
        exit();
    }
}
```

The htaccess rules for the thanks page are:

```
# Thanks Page
RewriteRule ^thanks/?$ thanks.php [QSA,L]
#RewriteRule ^thanks/$ thanks.php [QSA,L]
```

**Problem:**

The issue is the hash (#) character i.e. the fragment part is still sticking with the URL like:

```
http://www.example.com/thanks#contact
```

How does the part `#contact` get stick with main URL if I am redirecting the page to `thanks`?

How can we exclude/drop it either by htaccess or PHP or even through JS?

Comment: Your solution didn't work in firefox.

Answer (score 2):

This question is asked before.

[redirect is keeping hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12432212/redirect-is-keeping-hash)

The response marked as the answer was:

> > The simple answer to "how do I stop it" is to specify an empty hash in the Location header:
> >
> > `header('Location: /account.html#');`
> >
> > However, this behavior isn't guaranteed across the board. It seems to work in WebKit and IE9 in my quick test. Nevertheless, you've stumbled on a black hole in the HTTP specification.

Comment: Firstly, nobody had asked it so clearly like I did. Isn't it? Secondly the solution you referred is not acceptable as I tried it and it didn't work at all. It added unnecessarily # at the end of url. Does that make any sense?

Comment: In my opinion, it is just a workaround, not a good solution. But this is the solution I found, and at least in 2013, they claim it is a "black hole in the HTTP spec". Might be you'll have to live with it, unless someone has a more elegant solution

Comment: Actually, try the solutions here, one of them might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16773111/removing-anchor-hash-from-url

Comment: OK, I will try it later. But no one is telling me how is it behaving like this? How does the fragment part suffix with the main URL?