# How to remove anchor (#hash) from url after clicking a bookmark link

Tags: javascript, html

on the site example.html i have the link `href="index.html#section1`".
when you click the link, the url is index.html#section1, but is there a way to only display index.html but still go to the Id #section1 ?
I found this: [Removing anchor (#hash) from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16773111/removing-anchor-hash-from-url)
but i don't know how to use it since i only understand a little javascript. maybe someone can help out with a detailed instruction where to insert which code.

Comment: Hi edith.. you will need to remove the hash from URL only AFTER the anchoring action occurred (Still don`t get why you need to do this.. feel free to express yourself)

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the data after the hash without re-directing the page but you can re-name it with

location.hash = "new-location"